# Using QGIS Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to georeference a pdf into my QGIS project.

I am doing the exact same way as I have done many many times (same transformation settings, number of reference points...). After doing the georeferencing, the raster shows up in my layer panel but it is not visible. Whether I hide all other layers, change transparency, zoom to layer...the layer is there but invisible.
I'm using 3.4.10 (Madeira) which is the version I have been using for months

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?  If software behavior seems to have changed from the way Zi thought it always worked then my first thought is whether I’ve upgraded since doing it the last time.

Comment: I'm using 3.4.10 (Madeira) which is the version I have been using for months. I haven't received any notifications of upgrade requirements for qgis or the georeferencer. The georeferencer is actually the only tool who is showing this change in behavior

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved. In case anybody face the same problem, first check out your pdf source file. In my case, the pdf was already georeferenced and layered. I usually work with simple pdf image with no coordinates data at all. In this case, the pdf, which is apparently extracted from Arcmap, already has geographic data embedded in the file and using the qgis georeferencer seems to be breaking everything. To overlay this pdf in my project, I just had to load it as a raster. It opened right where it is supposed to be.

Comment: That might be worth making a bug report. It seems like unexpected behavior. I would expect QGIS to give a warning or error message when you try to georeference an already-georeferenced image.

Comment: @csk issue has been reported at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32722